# Classifying groups of order $12$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, solution-verification, sylow-theory

I want to classify all groups of order $12$.

Let $G$ be a group with $|G|=12$. Then $n_3=1$ or $4$.

1. If $n_3=4$ then we have $|G:\langle x \rangle |=4$ where $\langle x\rangle$ is a Sylow $3-$ subgroup (not normal in $G$) so we have a homomorphism $r:G\to S_4$ with $ker(r)\subseteq \langle x\rangle$ and $ker(r)\lhd G\Rightarrow ker(r)=\{1\}$ so $G$ is embedded in $S_4$ and has oredr $12$ hence $G\cong A_4$.
2. If $n_3=1$ then we have a unique Sylow $3-$ subgroup $P=\langle x\rangle$ and let $H$ a Sylow $2-$subgroup of $G$. Then $G= P\rtimes_u H$ where $u:H\to Aut(P)$ and $Aut(P)=Aut(\langle x\rangle)=\langle \tau\rangle,\ \tau:x\mapsto x^{-1}$, $|Aut(\langle x\rangle)|=2$.

- If $H\cong \mathbb{Z}_4=\langle y\rangle$ then we have $u:\langle y\rangle \to \langle \tau\rangle$

If $u$ is trivial then $u(y)(x)=x$ hence $yxy^{-1}=u(y)(x)=x$ so $G\cong \mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z}_4$

If $u(y)(x)=x^{-1}$ then $yxy^{-1}=x^{-1}$ so $G=\langle x,y| \ x^3=y^4=1,\ yxy^{-1}=x^{-1} \rangle$

-If $H\cong \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2=\langle a\rangle \times \langle b\rangle$ then we have $u:\langle a\rangle \times \langle b\rangle\to \langle \tau\rangle$

If $u$ is trivial then $G\cong \mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$

If $u(a)(x)=x^{-1}$ then $G=\langle a,b,x| \ a^2=b^2=1,\ axa^{-1}=x^{-1},\ bx=xb\rangle$

Hence we have $5$ non isomorphic groups of order $12$

> Question 1) Is the above proof correct?

> Question 2) I know I should have find $D\cong D_6$ somewhere but maybe I did something wrong or I can't see the prosentations correctly.

Comment: I think you'll find the question of classifying groups of order twelve has been asked and answered on this site before, maybe even several times. A search would be in order.

Comment: E.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14754/group-of-order-12 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1583743/finding-and-classifying-all-groups-of-order-12 and various links there.

Comment: I reckon your last group is the dihedral group.

Comment: @Angina Seng I know that I have to make a substitution in order to get its usual form but I can't see what exactly. Could you help me?

Comment: I presume $x$ is the order $3$ element. In which case $bx$ has order $6$.

Comment: Aa ok! Thanks!!

Comment: Argument (1) is correct but depends on knowing that A_4 is a unique subgroup of order 12 in S_4, is that easy to show?

Comment: @rain1 Maybe I'm wrong (I haven't written it down) but for $|H|=12, H\leq S_4$ it would be the case that $H$ contains all of $3-$ cycles hence $A_4$. Is this correct?

Comment: That is great, closes that gap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is good. I think it can be structured more clearly and the groups can be explicitly identified. We know that the following groups exist:

- Abelian: $C_{12}$, $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_3$.
- Non-Abelian: $A_4$, $D_6$, $\mathrm{Dic}_3$ (Also known as the *dicyclic*, or *metacyclic* group of order 12).

Sylow theory tells us that the Sylow 3-subgroups will be $C_3$, and the Sylow 2-subgroups will be $C_4$ or $C_2 \times C_2$. We also learn that:

- $n_2 = 1$ or $3$.
- $n_3 = 1$ or $4$.

When $n_2 = n_3 = 1$ we have the Abelian groups.

When $n_3 = 4$ you showed that we have $A_4$.

We can now look at the only remaining case: $n_3 = 1$ and $n_2 = 4$. In this situation we are searching for the nontrivial semidirect products $C_3 \rtimes_\theta P_2$ with $\theta : P_2 \to \operatorname{Aut}(C_3)$.

Note that $\operatorname{Aut}(C_3) \simeq \langle id, inv \rangle \simeq C_2$

Let's split into cases based on what $P_2$ is.

(**Case A**) $P_2 = C_4$:

In this case there is exactly one nontrivial homomorphism which is forced from $\theta(0) = 0$ and $\theta(1) = 1$. This gives us the metacyclic group, $Dic_3$.

(**Case B**) $P_2 = C_2 \times C_2$:

In this case there are 3 different nontrivial homomorphisms:

- $\theta_a(0,0) = 0$, $\theta_b(0,0) = 0$, $\theta_c(0,0) = 0$
- $\theta_a(0,1) = 1$, $\theta_b(0,1) = 0$, $\theta_c(0,1) = 1$
- $\theta_a(1,0) = 0$, $\theta_b(1,0) = 1$, $\theta_c(1,0) = 1$
- $\theta_a(1,1) = 1$, $\theta_b(1,1) = 1$, $\theta_c(1,1) = 0$

Now these's actually all give us isomorphic semidirect products because we have automorphisms of $P_2$ that relate these maps to each other:

- $(a,b) \mapsto (a,b)$
- $(a,b) \mapsto (b,a)$
- $(a,b) \mapsto (a,ab)$

Now we can use $\theta_a$ and the definition of multiplication of elements in a semidirect product to see that $C_3 \rtimes_{\theta_a} C_2 \times C_2 \simeq S_3 \times C_2 \simeq D_{6}$.